# angularjs filter week in simple grid table

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Im trying to get last week number ...and filter my grid table with last week data in angularjs...

 so in **controller** :

```js
    Date.prototype.getWeek = function() {
      var onejan = new Date(this.getFullYear(), 0, 1);
      return Math.ceil((((this - onejan) / 86400000) + onejan.getDay() + 1) / 7);
    }

    var weekNumber = (new Date()).getWeek() - 3; //for last week

    $scope.pastWeek = weekNumber;

    console.log($scope.pastWeek); //today is sunday 12 mar 2016..so output-9
    console.log(weekNumber);

    var pastWeek = $filter('date')( $scope.pastWeek , 'w');
    console.log(pastWeek); //but here output is 01... why..!!
```

here in pastWeek im expecting 09 as output ... i must be wrog somewhere.. do help  *thanks in advance*

Answer (score 0):

```
Date.prototype.getWeek = function() {
        var onejan = new Date(this.getFullYear(), 0, 1);
        return Math.ceil((((this - onejan) / 86400000) + onejan.getDay() + 1) / 7);
    }

    var weekNumber = (new Date()).getWeek();
```

This way you can get the last week number.

Comment: i dint get the number i got this as output "Sun Mar 06 2016 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)"